# How can I declare variables in a .h file that are common across a number of .m files

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a .h file that I want to use for several (five) .m files as they all have a lot in common. I'm currently working in Sprite-Kit.

Firstly, would I organise the .h file like so?

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>


@interface GameScene : SKScene // 1st .m file

@end


@interface GameScene2 : SKScene // 2nd .m file

@end


@interface GameScene3 : SKScene // 3rd .m file

@end


@interface GameScene4 : SKScene // 4th .m file

@end


@interface GameScene5 : SKScene // 5th .m file

@end
```

Now, where would I declare common variables for them? Would it be possible to declare common methods here also?

Comment: It sounds like you want to declare a subclass of SKScene and then have each of your game scenes inherit from that class

Comment: Thank you! Any advice on how I can do this? @Paulw11

Comment: By "common" do you mean variables that all instances of all the classes *share*, i.e. there is only one instance of each variable, or variables that each instance has their own copy of, i.e. there are multiple distinct variables all with the same name and type?